# How should I re-use React hooks setX from useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components that are basically like this:

```
// use-error-msg.jsx
function useErrorMsg(defaultMessage) {
  const [errorMsg, setError] = useState(defaultMessage);

  return errorMsg;
}

// Layout.jsx
function Layout() {
  const errorMsg = useErrorMsg('');
  const error = (errorMsg) ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : ''
  return <div>
    {error}
    <ComponentWithButton />
  </div>
}

// ComponentWithButton.jsx
function ComponentWithButton() {
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => {useErrorMsg('Something failed')}}>Click</button>
  </div>
}
```

I get that I can do `const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = setState('');`. I'm not sure how it can re-used if I drop that into its own function, given that my current example errors that I'm not in a function component when clicking the button.

I saw the examples in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) for `useFriendStatus`, which essentially lets you reuse a getter and setter if you can set the value using an effect. Considering I want to set the value based on hitting a button, I'm not sure what I'm meant to do.

Comment: Hooks are for sharing stateful logic, not sharing state. You won't share the same state between your `Layout` and `ComponentWithButton`. You most likely want to pass down a state-altering function to `ComponentWithButton` instead, and keep the state in the `Layout`, like you are used to with class components.

Comment: But if my project gets more complicated and ComponentWithButton is 3 levels deep, I'd need to keep passing down the `setErroMsg` method all the way through, no?

Comment: Yes, or use context, or an external state management library like Redux or MobX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is use your setError function to alter the state. As you can see I pass down the setError function to the component down. If you want to go deeper maybe check `useContext`.

```
// use-error-msg.jsx
function useErrorMsg(defaultMessage) {
  const [errorMsg, setError] = useState(defaultMessage);

  return [errorMsg, setError];
}


// Layout.jsx
function Layout() {
  const [errorMsg, setError] = useErrorMsg('');
  const error = (errorMsg) ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : ''
  return <div>
    {error}
    <ComponentWithButton setError={setError} />
  </div>
}

// ComponentWithButton.jsx
function ComponentWithButton(props) {
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => {props.setError('Something failed')}}>Click</button>
  </div>
}
```

Example with context. https://codesandbox.io/s/l90p3023yl

```
// use-error-msg.jsx
function useErrorMsg(defaultMessage) {
  const [errorMsg, setError] = useState(defaultMessage);

  return [errorMsg, setError];
}

// error-context.jsx
import React from 'react';

const ErrorContext = React.createContext()

function ErrorProvider(props) {
  const [errorMsg, setError] = useErrorMsg('');

  return (
    <ErrorContext.Provider value={{ errorMsg, setError }}>
      {props.children}
    </ErrorContext.Provider>
  )
}

// App.jsx

function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorProvider>
      <Layout />
    </ErrorProvider>
  )
}

// Layout.jsx
function Layout() {
  const { errorMsg } = useContext(ErrorContext);
  const error = (errorMsg) ? <div>{errorMsg}</div> : ''
  return <div>
    {error}
    <ComponentWithButton />
  </div>
}

// ComponentWithButton.jsx
function ComponentWithButton(props) {
  const { setError } = useContext(ErrorContext);
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => {setError('Something failed')}}>Click</button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: You answered just as I wrote this comment above: If my project gets more complicated and ComponentWithButton is 3 levels deep, I'd need to keep passing down the setErroMsg method all the way through, no?

Comment: I just edit, I will maybe use useContext if you want to use deeper

Comment: @DaveStein I just put an example with context

Comment: Both learning together :) You shouldn't need to wrap `<Layout>` with `<ErrorProvider>`.

Comment: Gimme a sec, I'll drop something in that is working and give you the selected answer instead of me making minor tweak and claiming anything ;)

Comment: @DaveStein Perfect I give you the code here you can play https://codesandbox.io/s/l90p3023yl

Comment: It seems you are right. It's just odd that you can do `useContext` as part of new API,  which drops the need for `Context.Consumer`, but you still have to use `Context.Provider`

Comment: Yes need the Provider, like you I was surprised. Maybe they will remove it in the future. But now I think the issue if we don't provide the provider is how the useContext know what you pass.